# Finding the com..... to use in Android Layout

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-actionbar, titlebar

I am using [this tutorial](http://thiranjith.com/2011/07/15/actionbar-design-pattern-example-for-android/) to try to replace the default TitleBar with a custom ActionBar.  I am to the part where I am trying to create the xml layout for the custom title (#2 Under INCLUDING THE ACTIONBAR WIDGET IN YOUR APPLICATION), and the tutorial defines the ActionBar in the xml using

```
com.thira.examples.actionbar.widget.ActionBar
```

I have no idea how to figure out what to put there for my ActionBar.  I believe this is called the package name.  If so, how do I figure out what mine is.  If not, what am I looking for here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple options for figuring out your package name. The first (and easiest) is to declare it yourself in the project properties dialog:

[image]

Alternatively, if you haven't defined it yourself you can take a look at the AndroidManifest.xml file that is generated as part of the packaging step of the build. You can find it in the obj/Debug/android folder of your project.

Comment: Thanks. I've provided the package name in my manifest, yet still can't create the ActionBar in my xml.  The package name is app.cpecfieldapp.  The namespace the ActionBar is in is CPECFieldApp and the object itself is named ActionBar just like in the tutorial.  I just get an "element is not declared" error when I try to reference it in the xml like <app.cpecfieldapp.actionbar.widget.ActionBar>

Comment: That's just a warning in Visual Studio, since it has no way of knowing about that element since it's not part of the schema it has. You can ignore it.

Comment: That example is making less and less sense.  I may just try to find a different one.  You don't happen to have an example of using an ActionBar in MonoDroid do you?  Preferably one that I can then place a TabLayout under.