# Properly extending EditText class for Mono Android

Tags: android, inheritance, android-widget, android-edittext, xamarin.android

I am trying to extend the EditText class in Android Mono for overriding purposes. Here is what I have so far code wise. Unfortunately, it crashes when I try to run it (it doesn't crash of course when I use a standard EditText widget instead).

```
namespace testing
{
    public class SuperEditText : EditText
    {
        public SuperEditText(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        // Java has init() here - maybe that's an issue. If so, does C# have an equivalent?
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the XML:

```
<SuperEditText
    android:id="@+id/eta"      
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
/>
```

Any ideas?

****************** EDIT FOR DEBUG LOG:

```
04-13 17:44:13.743 D/AndroidRuntime(  476): 
04-13 17:44:13.743 D/AndroidRuntime(  476): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-13 17:44:13.743 D/AndroidRuntime(  476): CheckJNI is ON
04-13 17:44:14.713 D/AndroidRuntime(  476): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
04-13 17:44:14.773 I/ActivityManager(   79): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=484 uid=10003 gids={1015, 2001}
04-13 17:44:15.373 D/dalvikvm(  484): GC_EXPLICIT freed 286K, 54% free 2568K/5511K, external 410K/517K, paused 94ms
04-13 17:44:15.723 W/ActivityManager(   79): No content provider found for: 
04-13 17:44:15.763 W/ActivityManager(   79): No content provider found for: 
04-13 17:44:15.783 D/PackageParser(   79): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl-636945189.tmp
04-13 17:44:16.093 D/dalvikvm(   79): GC_CONCURRENT freed 502K, 43% free 4211K/7367K, external 710K/1222K, paused 9ms+11ms
04-13 17:44:16.333 I/PackageManager(   79): Removing non-system package:HelloM4A.HelloM4A
04-13 17:44:16.333 I/ActivityManager(   79): Force stopping package HelloM4A.HelloM4A uid=10036
04-13 17:44:16.523 D/PackageManager(   79): Scanning package HelloM4A.HelloM4A
04-13 17:44:16.523 I/PackageManager(   79): Package HelloM4A.HelloM4A codePath changed from /data/app/HelloM4A.HelloM4A-2.apk to /data/app/HelloM4A.HelloM4A-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
04-13 17:44:16.523 I/PackageManager(   79): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/HelloM4A.HelloM4A-1.apk
04-13 17:44:16.593 D/installd(   35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/HelloM4A.HelloM4A-1.apk' ---
04-13 17:44:17.333 D/dalvikvm(  495): DexOpt: load 154ms, verify+opt 353ms
04-13 17:44:17.353 D/installd(   35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/HelloM4A.HelloM4A-1.apk' (success) ---
04-13 17:44:17.363 W/PackageManager(   79): Code path for pkg : HelloM4A.HelloM4A changing from /data/app/HelloM4A.HelloM4A-2.apk to /data/app/HelloM4A.HelloM4A-1.apk
04-13 17:44:17.363 W/PackageManager(   79): Resource path for pkg : HelloM4A.HelloM4A changing from /data/app/HelloM4A.HelloM4A-2.apk to /data/app/HelloM4A.HelloM4A-1.apk
04-13 17:44:17.363 D/PackageManager(   79): Registered content provider: HelloM4A.HelloM4A.__mono_init__, className = mono.MonoRuntimeProvider, isSyncable = false
04-13 17:44:17.363 D/PackageManager(   79):   Providers: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
04-13 17:44:17.363 D/PackageManager(   79):   Receivers: mono.android.Seppuku
04-13 17:44:17.363 D/PackageManager(   79):   Activities: hellom4a.Activity1
04-13 17:44:17.373 I/ActivityManager(   79): Force stopping package HelloM4A.HelloM4A uid=10036
04-13 17:44:17.543 I/installd(   35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@HelloM4A.HelloM4A-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@HelloM4A.HelloM4A-1.apk@classes.dex
04-13 17:44:17.543 D/PackageManager(   79): New package installed in /data/app/HelloM4A.HelloM4A-1.apk
04-13 17:44:17.713 I/ActivityManager(   79): Force stopping package HelloM4A.HelloM4A uid=10036
04-13 17:44:17.833 D/dalvikvm(  164): GC_EXPLICIT freed 59K, 52% free 2906K/5959K, external 1221K/1532K, paused 100ms
04-13 17:44:17.933 I/ActivityManager(   79): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=496 uid=10009 gids={}
04-13 17:44:17.993 W/RecognitionManagerService(   79): no available voice recognition services found
04-13 17:44:18.783 I/ActivityThread(  496): Pub com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
04-13 17:44:18.853 D/dalvikvm(   79): GC_CONCURRENT freed 560K, 43% free 4255K/7431K, external 710K/1222K, paused 9ms+29ms
04-13 17:44:19.103 D/dalvikvm(  295): GC_CONCURRENT freed 296K, 52% free 2738K/5703K, external 555K/1024K, paused 7ms+18ms
04-13 17:44:19.153 D/dalvikvm(   79): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47K, 44% free 4209K/7431K, external 710K/1222K, paused 252ms
04-13 17:44:19.493 I/installd(   35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@HelloM4A.HelloM4A-2.apk@classes.dex
04-13 17:44:19.513 D/AndroidRuntime(  476): Shutting down VM
04-13 17:44:19.543 D/dalvikvm(  476): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 72% free 293K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+2ms
04-13 17:44:19.553 I/AndroidRuntime(  476): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-13 17:44:19.553 D/jdwp    (  476): adbd disconnected
04-13 17:44:20.513 D/AndroidRuntime(  509): 
04-13 17:44:20.513 D/AndroidRuntime(  509): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-13 17:44:20.513 D/AndroidRuntime(  509): CheckJNI is ON
04-13 17:44:21.483 D/AndroidRuntime(  509): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
04-13 17:44:21.553 I/ActivityManager(   79): Start proc HelloM4A.HelloM4A for broadcast HelloM4A.HelloM4A/mono.android.Seppuku: pid=517 uid=10036 gids={3003, 1015}
04-13 17:44:21.893 I/ActivityThread(  517): Pub HelloM4A.HelloM4A.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
04-13 17:44:21.913 D/dalvikvm(  517): Trying to load lib /data/data/HelloM4A.HelloM4A/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x405135d8
04-13 17:44:21.913 D/dalvikvm(  517): Added shared lib /data/data/HelloM4A.HelloM4A/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x405135d8
04-13 17:44:22.253 I/monodroid-gc(  517): environment supports jni NewWeakGlobalRef
04-13 17:44:22.613 D/Zygote  (   33): Process 517 exited cleanly (255)
04-13 17:44:22.613 I/ActivityManager(   79): Process HelloM4A.HelloM4A (pid 517) has died.
04-13 17:44:22.623 D/AndroidRuntime(  509): Shutting down VM
04-13 17:44:22.663 I/AndroidRuntime(  509): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-13 17:44:22.663 D/dalvikvm(  509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 69% free 319K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
04-13 17:44:22.663 D/jdwp    (  509): adbd disconnected
04-13 17:44:23.563 D/AndroidRuntime(  531): 
04-13 17:44:23.563 D/AndroidRuntime(  531): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-13 17:44:23.563 D/AndroidRuntime(  531): CheckJNI is ON
04-13 17:44:24.733 D/AndroidRuntime(  531): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
04-13 17:44:24.793 I/ActivityManager(   79): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=HelloM4A.HelloM4A/hellom4a.Activity1 } from pid 531
04-13 17:44:24.873 D/AndroidRuntime(  531): Shutting down VM
04-13 17:44:24.903 I/AndroidRuntime(  531): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-13 17:44:24.963 D/dalvikvm(  531): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 69% free 318K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+2ms
04-13 17:44:24.963 D/jdwp    (  531): adbd disconnected
04-13 17:44:25.003 I/ActivityManager(   79): Start proc HelloM4A.HelloM4A for activity HelloM4A.HelloM4A/hellom4a.Activity1: pid=540 uid=10036 gids={3003, 1015}
04-13 17:44:25.743 I/ActivityThread(  540): Pub HelloM4A.HelloM4A.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
04-13 17:44:25.853 D/dalvikvm(  540): Trying to load lib /data/data/HelloM4A.HelloM4A/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x40513a08
04-13 17:44:25.853 D/dalvikvm(  540): Added shared lib /data/data/HelloM4A.HelloM4A/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x40513a08
04-13 17:44:26.233 I/monodroid-gc(  540): environment supports jni NewWeakGlobalRef
04-13 17:44:30.233 I/MonoDroid(  540): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type 'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown.
04-13 17:44:30.283 E/mono    (  540): 
04-13 17:44:30.283 E/mono    (  540): Unhandled Exception: Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type 'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown.
04-13 17:44:30.343 D/Zygote  (   33): Process 540 exited cleanly (1)
04-13 17:44:30.343 I/ActivityManager(   79): Process HelloM4A.HelloM4A (pid 540) has died.
04-13 17:44:30.492 W/InputManagerService(   79): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40676960
04-13 17:44:35.733 D/dalvikvm(  295): GC_EXPLICIT freed 57K, 53% free 2723K/5703K, external 555K/1024K, paused 86ms
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to prefix the name of the element with the Java version of the namespace it is in. For example, if your namespace is `testing`, the XML should look like:

```
<testing.SuperEditText
    android:id="@+id/eta"      
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top" />
```

Some more details on finding/setting your Java namespace can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826035/finding-the-com-to-use-in-android-layout/9826165#9826165).

**EDIT**

I reproduced this locally in order to get the exception, which ended up being:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to find a constructor with signature (Android.Content.Context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet) on type MonoAndroidApplication23.SuperEditText.  Please provide the missing constructor.

You can fix this by updating your constructor to look like this:

```
public SuperEditText(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
    : base(context, attrs)
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think I tried using the namespace before. Anyway, I tried again, but the app still crashes. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log

Comment: Thanks for your help. I posted the log, and I think I've found the answer after a bit of research. My project name was "HelloM4A" (which isn't my name, but was given from the tutorial from Xamarin). The capital letters were the culprit. Java doesn't like them. I discovered this after hunting for this error: "UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type 'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown"

Comment: Perhaps you can update your answer to include this info, and then I can tick it. By the way, just to add that yes, your constructor was also needed.

Comment: Yeah, that's why my first answer was to look up the Java version of your namespace since that's what needs to be used in the layout XML. You can set it yourself or look it up in the manifest.

Comment: Interestingly, you can call the package name (from project properties) anything (and even ignore the package name given in the AndroidManifest.XML file). Neither of those seem to matter. What DOES matter is the namespace in the actual project code (that's the one to use in the AXML file). At least in my experience.